# MigraDoc.Extensions HTML to PDF Conversion

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to convert  HTML into PDF doc using MigraDoc and HTML conversion extension available at. https://github.com/benfoster/MigraDoc.Extensions

While parsing following sample html, extension returns main Table TAG with appending child table rows to parent table. Has any one tried parsing nested table using this extension.

HTML

```
   <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             "text data"
         </td>
      </tr>


<tr>
   <td>
    <table border="1px">
         <tr><td>ID</td>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td>Experience</td></tr>

        <tr><td>1</td>
            <td>Ravi</td>
            <td>4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>2</td>
            <td>Raju</td>
            <td>4</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td> Footer Text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Looking for any suggestions for converting html to PDF with nested tables.

Thanks,
Ramesh